# What is the difference between findBy with underscore and findBy without it?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, backend

Example: What is the difference between :

```
List<UserCompany> findByCompany_IdAndCompany_IsActivated(params)
   and 
List<UserCompany> findByCompanyIdAndCompanyIsActivated(params)
```

Comment: No difference ..just for better readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference if your model is unambiguous with respect to field names.

```
List<UserCompany> findByCompanyIdAndCompanyIsActivated(params) -
```

this first thinks that companyId and companyIsActivated are properties within UserCompany and tries to find them if fails
it then thinks that UserCompany has a field Company - which is another class and Company has field - Id and IsActivated  and tries to find them

Where as the below thing

```
List<UserCompany> findByCompany_IdAndCompany_IsActivated(params)
```

assumes directly that UserCompany has a field Company - which is another class and Company has field - Id and IsActivated  and tries to find them

From the spring documentation

> Property expressions :---
> Property expressions can refer only to a direct
> property of the managed entity, as shown in the preceding example. At
> query creation time you already make sure that the parsed property is
> a property of the managed domain class. However, you can also define
> constraints by traversing nested properties. Assume Persons have
> Addresses with ZipCodes. In that case a method name of
>
> List findByAddressZipCode(ZipCode zipCode); creates the
> property traversal x.address.zipCode. The resolution algorithm starts
> with interpreting the entire part (AddressZipCode) as the property and
> checks the domain class for a property with that name (uncapitalized).
> If the algorithm succeeds it uses that property. If not, the algorithm
> splits up the source at the camel case parts from the right side into
> a head and a tail and tries to find the corresponding property, in our
> example, AddressZip and Code. If the algorithm finds a property with
> that head it takes the tail and continue building the tree down from
> there, splitting the tail up in the way just described. If the first
> split does not match, the algorithm move the split point to the left
> (Address, ZipCode) and continues.
>
> Although this should work for most cases, it is possible for the
> algorithm to select the wrong property. Suppose the Person class has
> an addressZip property as well. The algorithm would match in the first
> split round already and essentially choose the wrong property and
> finally fail (as the type of addressZip probably has no code
> property). To resolve this ambiguity you can use _ inside your method
> name to manually define traversal points. So our method name would end
> up like so:
>
> List findByAddress_ZipCode(ZipCode zipCode);

Answer (score 0):

Underscore is reserved character which allows you to point the right object to construct jpa query. It's used only with nested objects. For example if you would like to query by ZipCode inside Address inside you Company object.

More information can be found [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions)